# Why does collection_names() return an empty array when I know there is a collection there?

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm trying to wrap my head around how MonogoDB stores information. I have successfully uploaded the "restaurants" collection to the "test" database from the monogodb upload tutorial. I know this, because I can print the entire collection in the console.

HOWEVER.

When i run the following code:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import Connection
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pprint

connection = Connection()

print connection.database_names()

db = connection['test']

print db.collection_names(include_system_collections=False)

pprint.pprint(db.restaurants.find_one())
```

I get the following output:

```
C:\scripts>mongodbtest.py
[u'development', u'local', u'test']
[]
{u'_id': ObjectId('59c1a2a757b3f662e0f8eb52'),
 u'address': {u'building': u'2780',
              u'coord': [-73.98241999999999, 40.579505],
              u'street': u'Stillwell Avenue',
              u'zipcode': u'11224'},
 u'borough': u'Brooklyn',
 u'cuisine': u'American',
 u'grades': [{u'date': datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 10, 0, 0),
              u'grade': u'A',
              u'score': 5},
             {u'date': datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 5, 0, 0),
              u'grade': u'A',
              u'score': 7},
             {u'date': datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 13, 0, 0),
              u'grade': u'A',
              u'score': 12},
             {u'date': datetime.datetime(2011, 10, 12, 0, 0),
              u'grade': u'A',
              u'score': 12}],
 u'name': u'Riviera Caterer',
 u'restaurant_id': u'40356018'}
```

Why does the collection_names() come up with an empty array?!?!?!?!

Comment: What are your specific versions of PyMongo and MongoDB server?

Comment: I'm using mongodb 3.4 and the latest version of pymongo. the installation happened 3 days ago.

Comment: I believe you were asked because `from pymongo import Connection` is not actually valid in the *"latest version of pymongo"*. You should be establishing your connection with `MongoClient()`. And provided you are not required to provide any credentials for access to the local database where you know you have not already set up any users for authentication, then the claim ( with the correct class ) does not actually reproduce. Check your actual pymongo version and make sure you use `MongoClient()`. Also confirm that you are not meant to be authenticating and rule out a permissions issue

Comment: I used connection = MongoClient() using pymongo 2.7.2 still the same issue.

Comment: mongoengine==0.8.7, pymongo==2.7.2

Comment: I updated mongoengine and pymongo. With MongoClient() it worked. Thank you so much for your help Neil!